# Detect customer profile changes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to figure how to write a LINQ query that return a list of customers who changed their address on a given date

```
Cusomters
- Name (nvarchar)
- Address (nvarchar)
- CheckInDate (datetime)
```

I would first get a list of customers who checked in on a certain date then loop through each customer and get that customer's check ins to see if there are changes. This would result in numerous database queries. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: From your `Customers` schema above the query to get all customers who checked in on or before a given date is simple. I don't see where you're keeping a record of when they made changes.

Comment: I would take the a customer's last two check ins can compare the Address field

Comment: By the schema, I am assuming there is no denormalization taking place.  The address for "Customer A" may be different on their next check-in.

Comment: If the address for Customer A is different on their next check in then Customer A will be part of the returned list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will detect all customers who changed their addresses by `yourDate`.

```
var result = Customers.Where(c=>c.CheckInDate <= yourDate)
                      .GroupBy(c=>c.Name)
                      .Where(g=>g.GroupBy(c=>c.Address).Count() > 1)
                      .SelectMany(x=>x);
```